# Is it possible to perform node-level classification and graph-level classification on the same graph?

Tags: deep-learning, graph-neural-networks, gnn

I would like to classify the nodes of each graph in a multigraph, and transform the graph structure (or delete some of the nodes).
And then I want to do a graph-level classification problem.

Are there any methods or models to achieve this?
I have no idea how to do the labels.

I look forward to helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, it's called multitask learning, check this [paper](https://grlearning.github.io/papers/132.pdf) as a starting example.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you so much.